# Automatically edit word documents using C#

Tags: c#, matlab, vba

I have an exisent word document, FinalReport.docx with its own template, which I actually edit manually: the title, some paragraphs and the content of some tables are taken from other Matlab documents, let's say file1.m, file2.m, etc.
Finally I need to update the FinalReport index.
I'd like to do this automatically, maybe using C# or VBA. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What you're trying to do is certainly possible in C#. However, in order to help you, we would need to see what you have tried sofar. The community is ready to help when / if you get stuck with a specific coding problem somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit Word documents with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace. Google that to find tutorials on the subject ([here's one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264733%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). It requries that you have MS Word installed, which I don't think is a problem if you are first completing a manual step on the same computer. It uses a COM interface to control Word.

It's easier than the Open XML SDK for simple things like this, but the Open XML SDK will work better for advanced operations (creating reports on a server, for example). And  the SDK doesn't require you to install MS Word.

VBA can be used to do this also, which would be better for a beginner, because you can use the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) to get you started, then manually edit the VBA it generates to add things you can't do with the macro recorder.

I've done all three of these before. If this is your first experience automating MS Word tasks, I recommend you start with VBA.

Comment: How about Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)? Does it include Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word or do they have different purposes?

Comment: VSTO has a different purpose. It lets office host the .NET runtime so that you can customize Office using .NET languages (which VBA is not). This is a different way of doing it than the COM interface used by Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Seems like overkill unless you're planning on distributing your work to people you don't know.

Comment: I understand. So VSTO is more powerfull, isn't it? Anyway, I'm actually using VBA and even if I have never used it before I' m being able to write some code. Using Range, Paragraphs, Sections and Words allow you to manipulate a word text naturally. I think I'll get my solution quite soon and then I need to extend my code to manipulate Excel as well. So I'll go with VBA for now and I'll switch to Microsoft.Office.Interop as soon as I get something that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and edit .docx (Open XML) files using the Open XML SDK from Microsoft. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850833.aspx) for common editing operations and if what you need is listed, just download the SDK and follow the examples.