# Editing word document report generated by reporting tools

Tags: c#, .net, report, dynamic-reports, dynamic-rdlc-generation

i want to edit the report after generating from any reporting tools. currently i am using RDLC for generating report however i am unable to edit the word document after exporting.

here are some requirements:

- Add  new content by pasting from the other documents
- Simply add/remove some pages to the word report
- paste tables, pictures with further content should be automatically moved

Comment: if you are open to using Reporting tool then use Crystal reports or Devexpress Reporting tool they are easy and work well with a huge amount of data. Exporting is not an issue for both tools.

Comment: [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically edit word documents using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798401/automatically-edit-word-documents-using-c-sharp)

Comment: i want to edit the word document manually